# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs

Tags: php, mysqli

Quiero comparar dos tablas informacion igual y quiero saber cuales coinsiden y cuales no

```js
<?php
                    //Clase para manejar la conexion a la base de datos
                    class Connect
                    {
                        private $user = "root";//usuario de mysqlk
                        private $pass = "";//clave de mysql
                        private $base = "radius";//base de datos en mysql
                        private $server = "localhost";//servidor de alojamiento
                        public $error;//en caso de error se almacena aqui
                        public $db;
                        public function __construct(){
                            $mysqli = new mysqli($this->server, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->base);
                            if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
                                $this->error = "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
                            }
                            $this->db = $mysqli;
                        }
                    }
                    //Clase trabajo que se extiende de Connect
                    class Trabajo extends Connect
                    {
                        public function __construct(){
                            parent::__construct();
                        }
                        public function valida($x){
                                $a = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM archivos_de_pagos WHERE referencia = '$x' ");
                                $t = $a->num_rows;

                                if($t>=1){
                                    //Si el cliente realizó el pago retorno la información
                                    $row = $a->fetch_object();
                                    return $row;
                                }else{
                                    //si no retorno falso
                                    return false;
                                }
                        }//
                        public function data(){
                            $a = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM pagos_pagina");
                            
                            echo "<table>
                                <thead>
                                    <th>Numero</th>
                                    <th>Cliente</th>
                                    <th>Estatus</th>
                                    <th>Referencia</th>
                                </thead>
                            ";
                            $con=1;
                            while($row = $a->fetch_object()){
                                //Envío a validar la referencia del cliente
                                $valida = $this->valida($row->referencia);
                                if($valida){
                                    echo "<tr>
                                            <td>".$con."</td>
                                            <td>".$row->nombre." ".$row->apellido."</td>
                                            <td>Pago Validado</td>
                                            <td>".$valida->referencia."</td>
                                        </tr>";
                                    }else{
                                    echo "<tr>
                                            <td>".$con."</td>
                                            <td>".$row->nombre." ".$row->apellido."</td>
                                            <td>Pago Invalido</td>
                                            <td>".$row->referencia."</td>
                                        </tr>";
                                }
                                $con++;
                            }
                            echo "</table>";
                        }
                    }
                    $p = new trabajo();
                    $p->data();
                    
                    ?>
```

me da el siguiente error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\superconex\login\nuevo.php on line 27

// esta e mi linea 27

```
$t = $a->num_rows;
```

la version de mi php es  PHP: 5.6.33

Comment: por curiosidad.. porque no haces un select con los inner join de todas los campos que quieres comparar?

Comment: Verifica que tanto el nombre de la tabla `archivos_de_pagos` y la columna `referencia`  sean correctos.